# JQuery - Submit form after calling preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault

I have a form like below,

```
<form id="compose" method="post" name="new_message">
<div id="new_message">
    <div>
        <label class="required" for="new_message_subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="new_message[subject]" id="new_message_subject">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="required" for="new_message_receiver">To</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="new_message[receiver]" id="new_message_receiver">
            <option value="2">fnamexxxxx lname</option>
            <option value="5">tester testerlast</option>
            <option value="7">bummer bumlast</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="required" for="new_message_content">Content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="new_message[content]" id="new_message_content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="new_message[Compose]" id="new_message_Compose" type="submit">Compose</button>
    </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="new_message[_token]" id="new_message__token">
</div>
```

and using the `preventDefault()` I have stopped the form submission and then used a bootstrap modal to for a confirmation message and you can see my Jquery function and the bootstrap modal below.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("compose").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var title   = $("#new_message_subject").val();
        var to      = $("#new_message_receiver :selected").text();
        var message = $("#new_message_content").val();

        $('#title').text(title);
        $('#to').text(to);
        $('#message').text(message);

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        $('#send').click(function(){
            // avoid preventDefault() and submit form code here
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Message send confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 id="title"></h4>
                <p><b>To</b></p>
                <p id="to"></p>
                <p><b>Message</b></p>
                <p id="message"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The scenario is when a user click the form submit button, then the bootstrap modal pops up and ask to confirm the form submission and if a user clicks the **Send** button, `id="send"` then form needs to do its action / submission.

Now what I am trying to do is when the user is click the **Send** button in the modal the form needs to be submitted. I have tried few ways of doing this but could not avoid the `preventDefault()` and submit the form.

Comment: have you tried `$('#compose').submit()`?

Comment: No I have not tried it. now its working with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your script code should be as below.

```
<script>
    $("#compose").submit(function (objEvent) {
        objEvent.preventDefault();
        var title = $("#new_message_subject").val();
        var to = $("#new_message_receiver :selected").text();
        var message = $("#new_message_content").val();
        $('#title').text(title);
        $('#to').text(to);
        $('#message').text(message);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $(this)[0].submit();
    })
</script>
```